# Linked List implement in Java

Tags: java, linked-list

i try to implement a linked list with java, but i have a problem the size of my list  can only be 2 Nodes long and than it will be overwritten.

Here is the code..

The Class for one Node:

```
public class ListElement
{
    private String content;

    private ListElement next;

    public ListElement(String content){
        if (content == null){
            System.out.println("NullpointerException");
        }
        this.content = content; 
    }

    public String getContent() { return content; }

    public String setContent(String content){
        this.content = content;
        return content;
    }

    public ListElement getNext(){
        return next;
    }

    public ListElement setNext(ListElement next){
        this.next = next;
        return next;
    }
}
```

The class for the list...

```
public class List
{
    public ListElement head;
    public ListElement next;

    public List()
    {
        // no-op
    }

    public  void append(String content)
    {
        if(head == null){
            this.head = new ListElement(content);
        }
        else{
            this.next = new ListElement(content);
            this.next.setNext(null);
            head.setNext(this.next);
            head.getNext();
        }
    }   
}
```

Thank you for your help and time

Comment: You could search on google there are many examples. First one (https://gist.github.com/es20641/1208340/06d598126d53b048058bc243cbc4e4dd7db9a23a)

Comment: Looking at your code, I expect it to do exactly as you said. You literally set `head`'s next instead of iterating through the list and adding one to the end.

Comment: What problem does your posted code have?

Answer (score 1):

It would be something like that. Search last element and once found you can add the new item.

```
//head not null
else{
    ListElement last = this.next;
    if(last == null){
        this.next = new ListElement(content)
    }
    else{
        while (last.getNext() != null){
            last = last.getNext()
        }
        last.setNext(new ListElement(content))
   }
}
```

You might also want to prevent cycles in your LinkedList and implement the Iterator interface

Answer (score 0):

It's not enough to set the next element along from the head of the list to be the element you wish to append.

You'll need to walk down the list till you find the end, and only then append the latest element there

Comment: ok, yes i understand. but i dont know how i can change the head to the tail(next). i thought its enough to write head.getNext()...

Comment: That element might still not be the end of the list - see @greg's answer to see how to get to the *end* of the list before adding things

Answer (score 0):

It's the way you're using this.next.

Try something like this:

```
public  void append(String content)
{
    if(head == null){
        this.head = this.next = new ListElement(content);
    }
    else{
        ListElement next = new ListElement(content);
        this.next.setNext(next);
        this.next = next;
    }
}
```